# Validation accuracy does not increase for binary classification using GNN

Tags: accuracy, overfitting, graph-neural-network, validation

I am trying to perform graph classification with GINConv model of GNN. I have tried everything from varying dropouts to weight decay (for L2 regularization), learning rate (1e-6 to 1e-3), batch normalization to varying batch sets. It still doesn't show any change. My dataset is a set of 8000 graphs (with varying vertices and edges) that contain label 0 or 1. There are 4000 graphs with label 0 and 4000 with label 1. I am using Adam optimizer.There are 6 layers in my model. Here is my code :

```
def __init__(self):#,init_eps=np.random.uniform(1.5, 99.5),learn_eps=True):
    super(Net, self).__init__()

    self.dropout = 0.3
    self.first_h = []
    self.nns = []
    self.convs = []
    self.linears = []
    self.pooling = global_mean_pool

    #layer 0
    self.first_h = Sequential(Linear(60, 50), BatchNorm1d(50), ReLU(),
            Linear(50, 50), BatchNorm1d(50), ReLU())
    self.linears.append(Linear(50, 2))
    #rest
    i = 50
    while(i >= 20):
        j = i - 10
        self.nns.append(Sequential(Linear(i, j), BatchNorm1d(j), ReLU(),
            Linear(j, j), BatchNorm1d(j), ReLU()))
        self.convs.append(GINConv(self.nns[-1], train_eps=9))
        self.linears.append(Linear(j, 2))
        i = j

    self.nns.append(Sequential(Linear(10, 2), BatchNorm1d(2), ReLU(),
        Linear(2, 2), BatchNorm1d(2), ReLU()))
    self.convs.append(GINConv(self.nns[-1], train_eps=9))
    self.linears.append(Linear(2, 2))

    self.nns = torch.nn.ModuleList(self.nns)
    self.convs = torch.nn.ModuleList(self.convs)
    self.linears = torch.nn.ModuleList(self.linears)


def forward(self, data, flag):
    out = 0
    x, edge_index, batch = data.x, data.edge_index, data.batch
    for layer in range(6):
        if layer == 0:
            x = self.first_h(x)
            out += F.dropout(self.pooling(self.linears[layer](x), batch), p=self.dropout)
        else:
            x = self.convs[layer-1](x, edge_index)
            out += F.dropout(self.linears[layer](self.pooling(x, batch)), p=self.dropout, training=self.training)
    return out
```

Optimizer and train/valid/test splits :

```
train_loader = DataLoader(data_list[0:8000], batch_size=8000, shuffle = True)
valid_loader = DataLoader(data_list[8000:9000], batch_size=1000, shuffle = True)
test_loader = DataLoader(data_list[9000:10000], batch_size=1000, shuffle = True)
```

Train code :

```
for epoch in range(1000):
    if(validVal < 0.4 and trainVal < 0.3):
        break
    trainVal = 0
    model.train()
    for batch,label in train_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        batch = batch.to(torch.device(device))
        out = model(batch,1)
        label = label.to(torch.device(device))
        loss = F.cross_entropy(out, label)
        trainVal += loss.cpu().detach().numpy()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    model.eval()
    for batch,label in valid_loader:
        batch = batch.to(torch.device(device))
        out = model(batch,0)
        label = label.to(torch.device(device))
        loss = F.cross_entropy(out, label)
        validVal = loss.cpu().detach().numpy()
        if(minValid > loss.cpu().detach().numpy()):
            minValid = loss.cpu().detach().numpy()
```

I have tested by varying number of epochs as well. I have tried almost every possible scenario to prevent overfitting, but it does not seem to work. Any suggestions how to go about it?

This is my obtained curve :
[image]

Comment: what is the average performance?

Comment: 50% for training and validation. If training accuracy goes higher than 50%, validation and test accuracy drops which clearly means I am stuck at 50% optimal performance.